# Will PHP code work slower after obfuscation process with OPcache?

Tags: php, virtual-machine, bytecode, opcache

According to this scheme after launch of the code it transforms to opcode (bytecode), stores in OPcache and then execute in Zend VM (Virtual machine). And next launches will not transform code, but use stored bytecode.

[image]

When I obfuscate code, I expect, that first launch can be slower (because of additional tokenization of the code and transforming it to bytecode), but next launch I expect should be as fast as original code.

But, real test shows me that obfuscate code works slower than original code. So my question: is bytecode from raw php and bytecode from obfuscated code not the same, so they work differently?

Comment: Unless your obfuscation is overly complicated, or calls into some licensing servers, I'd be surprised if you actually noticed a difference one way or another. But this is something you should be able to test by running with and without the opcache enabled.

Comment: I would say the opcodes include the complete deobfuscation. So this will slow it down.